# How do I get the absolute mouse co-ordinates when mouse is over a control

Tags: delphi, mouseevent

I want to get the absolute co-ordinates of the mouse when the mouse is over a control which has been placed on a host control.  E.g. Host control is a panel a button is placed on the panel.  I want to get the mouse co-ordinates relative to the panel when the mouse is over the button.

I have tried the obvious just to see what I get:

```
procedure TfmWorkingScreen.pnlScreenAreaMouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   StatusBar1.SimpleText := 'Left ' + IntToStr(X) + '  Right ' + IntToStr(Y);
end;
```

Clearly this will only work when the mouse is over the panel control.  Is there a way to get the required co-ordinates?

Comment: You can use `ClientToParent` method.

Answer (score 6):

Add an `OnMouseMove` event handler to the child control, the button in your example. In that `OnMouseMove` event handler you receive the `X` and `Y` cursor coordinates with respect to the child control's client area. If the host control is the immediate parent of the control whose `OnMouseMove` event has fired you use the control's [`ClientToParent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ClientToParent) method:

```
var
  PosRelParent: TPoint:
....
PosRelParent := (Sender as TControl).ClientToParent(Point(X, Y));
```

If the parent control may be further up the parent/child relationship you can pass the parent control to `ClientToParent`:

```
PosRelParent := (Sender as TControl).ClientToParent(Point(X, Y), TheParent);
```

If you wish to express the position relative to some arbitrary controls client area then you can do so by converting via screen coordinates, a global frame of reference.

```
var
  PosRelScreen, PosRelOtherControl: TPoint:
  OtherControl: TWinControl;
....
PosRelScreen := (Sender as TControl).ClientToScreen(Point(X, Y));
PosRelOtherControl := OtherControl.ScreenToClient(PosRelScreen);
```

As one final offering, you can use `GetMessagePos` to obtain the screen relative coordinates of the mouse for the last message retrieved by a call to `GetMessage`.

```
var
  MsgPos: TPoint;
....
MsgPos := TSmallPoint(GetMessagePos());
```

At this point you can use `SomeControl.ScreenToClient(MsgPos)` to get the coordinates of the cursor relative to that control's client area. Obviously it only makes sense to call `GetMessagePos` if you are in an event handler triggered by a queued mouse message.

Comment: It's worth to mention, that if you'd need to get position with respect to the control's directionality layout (LTR or RTL), you could use the [`MapWindowPoints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for `TWinControl` descendants.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen to your mouse outside your program aswell you need to create a mouse hook.

I'ver earlier summitted a article and source code to About.com : http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-hooks.htm

If this have you interest I would love to go deeper on then subject.